# Error writing .htaccess to protect Symfony Directories in Web App

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to publish my first Symfony Project in production, but I'm very worried about security, I have taken the following measures:

1) First: Delete on */var* these directories: cache, logs and sessions

2) Second: Changed of default name for cookie session (client side: symfony)

3) Trhee: Creating a *.htaccess* in root directory of application

My problem is about the .htaccess. The goal is dennied access to others directories of application like: */app, /src, /test, /var, /vendor*.

I'll write the follow rules in .htaccess and puted it in root directory of my app: *myDevelopedApp/.htaccess*.

```
.htaccess
#Checking if module is avalaible
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   #Using the rewrite engine
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   #Rewrite rule to redirect the request
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
<IfModule>
```

The problem it's not working, I can not access to web folder when I write the rules. Apache hides the application myDevelopedApp when I try to access it by browser

What I'm wrong?
Any other recommendation to improve security in production enviroment is welcome, thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

If your are really concerned about security you should follow the [Symfony best practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html). That means that only the `/web` folder should be accessible in the vhost.

Moreover if you initialized your project with a standard edition you should already have `.htaccess` files in the `app/` `src/` folders.

Comment: This is useful, it's important just have the web directory on public directory. Thanks so much. The .htaccess, works fine, the problem was about apache.

Answer (score 0):

htaccess file code

```
    .htaccess
    #Checking if module is avalaible
    
       #Using the rewrite engine
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       #Rewrite rule to redirect the request
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

and this code too on your .htaccess file

```
<pre>
.htaccess
#Checking if module is avalaible
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   #Using the rewrite engine
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /folder/ /*location address if localhost localhost/project */
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   #Rewrite rule to redirect the request
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
<IfModule>
</pre>
```

RewriteBase solve this problem